# Customise Laravel auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

In my `users` table, I have a column `rank` which corresponds to the permissions of users. If `rank > 0`, the user may log in and proceed, since `0` in `rank` means they're (temporarily) blocked or inactive. So what I'd need is to customise the `auth` middleware so only rank `> 0` are going to be authenticated whatsoever.

I did some research on it but didn't find where to put my code exactly.

EDIT: I earlier found how to manually authenticate a user featuring additional requirements (e.g. `rank > 0`), however, I'm using laravels built-in feature, so that doesn't help much:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

(it's `active` in this case (source: laravel documentation), but could be adjusted).

Comment: Thanks very much for voting down without proper explanation. Thanks, I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 1):

There is middleware in your `app/http/middleware` called `RedirectIfAuthenticated`

You will have to edit it to something like this:

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->rank > 0) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/home');
```

Also if you want to manually authenticate user like you wrote, you can check if rank and password on user object and then just use

```
Auth::login($user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my `RedirectIfAuthenticated` looks `if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }` so I wonder how exactly your solution works. Does it work for every page?

Comment: Well if user is authenticated it will proceed to request if its not it will be redirected to /home @FelixBlome

Answer (score 1):

There is a `credentials()` method in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait that you can override in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`. So, just add this to your LoginController:

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'email' => $request->{$this->username()},
        'password' => $request->password,
        'active' => 1, // yep, not rank, read below
    ];
}
```

If rank field has different values than 0 and 1, do not use it for this purpose and add an active field. Otherwise if you block a user, which means you set rank field to 0, how do you know what was the old rank when you unblock the user?